# kq_init warning when starting Spyder through the terminal on macOS

Tags: python, spyder, macos-high-sierra

I'm running Spyder on my Mac with High Sierra. I have 2 virtual environments defined using Anaconda. The virtual environments are py27 for python 2.7.13 and py36 for python 3.65. When I go to py36 and run Spyder, everything seems to work fine. When I go to py27, immediately after I start spyder from the command line I get 9 warnings written to the terminal. The warning is:

`[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0`

After these messages, Spyder opens using the correct version of python and seems to run fine.  My question is should I be concerned about these warnings, why do they occur when running in py27 but not py36, and is spyder running fine with these warnings.

Comment: Have you run: `conda update conda` in your defautt environment, & `conda update anaconda` in your 2.7 environment?

Comment: I tried that but in both environments but got the following error message: PackageNotInstalledError: Package is not installed in prefix.
  prefix: /Users/johnhanly/anaconda3/envs/py27
  package name: conda

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I went back and did a few things and now I can update conda and that suggestion worked. The warnings no longer appear.  If you want to write suggestion up as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run:
`conda update conda` in your default environment, & `conda update anaconda` in your 2.7 environment?

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a harmless warning, so you can safely ignore it.

*Note*: This is not a problem in Spyder, however we'll make the warning go away in our next version (Spyder **3.3**), to be released in June/2018.

Comment: Thanks for your help, An earlier suggestion in the comments worked to stop messages from appearing.