# Keep getting this error when trying to launch Spyder using anaconda 3

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Every time I've tried to launch Spyder from Anaconda, I get an error message displaying this. I can't figure out how to fix it.

[image: error message]

```
[warn] kq_init: detected broken kqueue; not using.: Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: How did you open it? What command did you use?

Comment: Please put your error in the text of the question, not in an image. Also how does the error in the image relate to the one in the text?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please remove this question. This is a duplicate of [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50479258/438386) question, which I'll answer shortly.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba and others, it can be closed as a duplicate if you give it enough close votes...

Comment: @nekomatic, the OP changed the question. Now this is not a duplicate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug in Python itself on macOS. You can get a fix for it by opening Terminal.app and running there

`conda update python python.app`